# Proposal of design-review tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Seven years ago, I asked [whether PCB review questions were on-topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2513/2028). I think they're generally acceptable when they fit certain guidelines. However, I noticed that we don't seem to have good tags to assign to such questions.

We do have a [review](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) that that's not used much (18 times). I think its purpose would be similar to the [identification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) tag. Therefore, I am checking with the community:

Would a [design-review](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-review) tag would be useful to add for questions seeking a review of the design, whether schematic or PCB?

Comment: The large part of the current [tag:review] questions are indeed design reviews. So why have a new, different [tag:design-review] tag, since it will be used to refer to the same kind of questions? I can't see any benefit of having two tags for the same thing, so it isn't quite clear. Do you suggest both these tag be synonyms? Do you suggest to rename [tag:review] to [tag:design-review]? Or are you actually suggesting to have two completely different tags? In the latter case, can you point out how this will be beneficial to the site?

Comment: @dim I was under the impression that the `review` tag was being under-utilized, and thinking that having `design-review` (either separate or renamed) would help make it more obvious for users to tag questions with. Perhaps an alias/synonym is warranted.

Comment: Design review questions are not that great anyway. What purpose do they serve? "Here, review my design", but this brings up many answers, a title to a question that only serves the OP. In almost all cases design review questions be made more specific to ask a question of where the OP has a problem. Instead of "here is my design" something like "I'm having trouble with the layout of this board, I don't understand if the trace size is acceptable" OR "My ground is split, is this OK?"

Comment: @laptop2d I agree, but at the time I posted this question, I was thinking of looking at such review questions to see if there were any I could respond to. I thought it might be useful to tag them consistently, but after reading the posted answer below, I basically changed my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) .  Searching on it is useless, and it's frowned upon in the stack exchange network

Just look at the results of a search for "design review"  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=design+review  The hits fall into a few categories.

The most common, to me at least, is just plain mediocre questions.  There's also a class of good questions that are undertagged, which decreases their value.  Many are good questions that have some very good tags, and adding a design review tag probably won't make them better.

For example, let's say I'm interested in constructing an rf circuit as a pcb, and I scan for design review questions.

Search on "rf" : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rf
Search on "rf design review": https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=rf+design+review
Search on "rf PCB": https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rf+pcb

The last looks to be the most useful search to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree - sometimes looking for questions specifically asking for design review may be a user's intent (thus searching on it has some utility). Second point, are you saying that review questions are frowned upon or that meta-tagging is frowned upon?

Comment: meta-tagging is certainly frowned on -- that's what I was referring to.  GOOD review questions are not frowned upon, but they tend to be rare.   Most are "Here's what I did, please offer suggestions"  instead of "I'm concerned with how I dealt with these bypass capacitors, what do you think?"  The former is bad, the latter, much better.  You can, in fact, legitimately put a review tag every time somebody asks "why isn't this circuit working", but it doesn't help anyone to do so.  I'd suggest that there's ALWAYS a more descriptive tag to be had, if it's a good question.

Comment: Fair points, thanks for the input.